# Does there exist a metric space of cardinality aleph-two that has a countable epsilon cover?

Tags: metric-spaces, set-theory

Does there exist a metric space $(M,d)$ such that $|M|=\aleph_2$ but there exists a countable $\epsilon$-cover of $M$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the question is whether there's a countable $\epsilon$-cover for *every* $\epsilon>0$.

And we really can't tell, because we don't know whether $\aleph_2>c$. The answer is no if $\aleph_2>c$ (and certainly yes if $\aleph_2\le c$):

If $M$ is a metric space and there is a countable $\epsilon$-cover for every $\epsilon>0$ then $|M|\le c$.

Proof: For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $S_n$ be a countable set such that the balls of radius $1/n$ with centers at points of $S_n$ cover $M$. Then for every $x$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\in S_n$ and $x_n\to x$. So there is a map from $\prod_{n<\omega}S_n$ onto $M$, hence $|M|\le c$.